# JavaFX execution has a bigger frame than SceneBuilder preview

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, builder, scene

I am making an UI with Scenebuilder and I noticed that this: (SceneBuilder preview)
[image: scenebuilderpreview]

Was sightly different than this: (Eclipse execution)
[image]

So I tried to make it simple (without dynamically added elements and those things).

Same results. This is the Scene Builder preview:
[image]

And this is on execution:
[image]

Every time I execute a Stage I get a system print which says:
[image]

> mar 22, 2018 12:17:21 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
> WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.101

Comment: "I was using an older JRE version than JavaFX was."  How was that even possible?  JavaFX is part of the JRE, so it always has the same version as the JRE that it is part of.

Comment: It is not appropriate to add (SOLVED) in your post title and edit the solution into your post, so I've removed it. If you've solved the problem and want to share that solution, do so by using the answer space below to do so properly as it says in [Can I answer my own question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If you don't want to be bothered writing that answer, you can either leave the question for someone else to answer, or you can choose to delete it.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, i just did that.

Comment: @jewelsea Scenebuilder was generating a fxml with this: xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" check the red error above, I'm not really used to jres and libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I was useing an older JRE version. I was useing javafx 9.0.1 and JRE 8.0.161

So i just downloaded JRE 9, changed it on Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> add

and created a new project, copied everything and it worked. Now the red error is not showing.

**Update: I ended downgrading again to 1.8... Its been imposible to manage all the problems that JRE 9 were giveing to me. I guess my destiny is to have a bigger window than I want...**

**Upadate 2: I downloades SceneBuilder 8. Now I don't get the compatibility error but the frame stills being better.**